# I need to change the page column width in sharepoint 2007 on the main page

Tags: sharepoint-2007, width

I have a few users that visit the primary sharepoint page, find that the right column width is really wide.  I have determined that it is by user account. My main account is fine, my secondary account has the column too wide.

I have tried the obvious steps, i.e. setting the column widths with sharepoint designer, changing all of the web parts in that column to a fixed pixel amount.  Nothing changes the column width for those where it is too wide.

The column width does change but only when the window size changes, like when the window is maximized.  It goes back to the original size when the window is placed back to normal.

A few years ago, I built our internal website with vb and asp.net.  I had some users that would get an error in their 'profile'.  I had to go into the database and delete that user, it would then work fine for them.  I did try removing the user profile under sharepoint but it didn't work either.

I am thinking that this is similar in that the width seems to be stored somewhere and reused each time the page is requested.

The problem occurs on different pcs.  I can login in with my main account and it is fine, I log in with my secondary account and it is too wide.

Same pc, same ie different log ins.  I don't know what to delete or reset to fix this issue.

I have run file cleaners and registry cleaners but no luck. It follows the user account.  Our user accounts are Active Directory accounts.

Thanks, In advance.

I wanted to add that I went to the site with Firefox and it did the same thing, too wide for my secondary account and just right with my main account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the Offical Solution.

The default.aspx page had been modified (by me) and not published.  So I
could see it but no one else could.

The Style resource readers group did not have authenticated users in it.

Also the style resoucre readers group wasn't in the Style Library or in the
Master page gallery.

So no one had permissions to any of those.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I seemed to have solved the issue but I still think there is a problem.  I have eight or nine web parts in that column.  I had to set three or four to a specific width in order to get the whole column to shrink down.  So my thoughts are that I had a few rogue web parts.  The problem that still seems to be there is that I have already forced the column itself to be a fixed width (through sharepoint designer).